# What is the meaning/use of "Owned Schemas"?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-administration

I am trying to understand the securables of SQL Server, I am not sure on what is the exact use of `OwnedSchema`. Can someone help me on this, where it plays a significant role?

[image]

Comment: You should find a good course, or read the documentation. This isn't something that can be answered in a few lines. SQL Server's documentation is *very* good. There are hundreds of good blog posts and articles. Microsoft covers this extensively in the free courses on it's Virtual Academy. And you can get 3 months free access to Pluralsight's courses through the (also free) Visual Studio Dev Essentials program

Comment: As well as not showing any research, this also doesn't seem to be about programming in any sense that is on-topic for SO. The DBA sister site would be more appropriate, but you would need to formulate a less vague/broad question first anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog on the picture enlist you all database's schemas and marks some schemas as "checked" if current database principal is the owner of these schemas.

So it shows you the result of this query (that you can catch using `Profiler`):

```
SELECT
s.name AS [Name],
s.schema_id AS [ID],
ISNULL(dp1.name, N'') AS [Owner],
CAST(
      case when s.name in ('dbo','guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA','sys','db_owner','db_accessadmin','db_securityadmin','db_ddladmin','db_backupoperator','db_datareader','db_datawriter','db_denydatareader', 'db_denydatawriter') then 1 else 0 end AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject]
FROM
sys.schemas AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp1 
   ON dp1.principal_id = s.principal_id
```

Using this dialog you can change the owner of the schema to current user, i.e. execute the following code:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[this_schema] TO [this_user]
```

This link is also useful to understand [Ownership and User-Schema Separation in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/ownership-and-user-schema-separation-in-sql-server).

> Schema Owners and Permissions
>
> Schemas can be owned by any database principal, and a single principal
>   can own multiple schemas. You can apply security rules to a schema,
>   which are inherited by all objects in the schema. Once you set up
>   access permissions for a schema, those permissions are automatically
>   applied as new objects are added to the schema. Users can be assigned
>   a default schema, and multiple database users can share the same
>   schema. By default, when developers create objects in a schema, the
>   objects are owned by the security principal that owns the schema, not
>   the developer. Object ownership can be transferred with ALTER
>   AUTHORIZATION Transact-SQL statement. A schema can also contain
>   objects that are owned by different users and have more granular
>   permissions than those assigned to the schema, although this is not
>   recommended because it adds complexity to managing permissions.
>   Objects can be moved between schemas, and schema ownership can be
>   transferred between principals. Database users can be dropped without
>   affecting schemas.